# Please help, Blender rendering videos really slow

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I'm new to blender, I've been using it to edit videos but While my videos are rendering my CPU usage sits around 15%, my RAM around 30% and my GPU doesn't get used at all. This doesn't seem right surely one of them should be near 100% anyone know whats going on?

[image]

Comment: Video Sequence Editor is single-threaded, so it is unfortunately that slow ... but will be improved in future versions. As a temporary workaround, you can try this tool: https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController